# Change ploting font globally or on a per-session basis

Tags: r, fonts, plot

I have a 2k lines script that generates several complex plots (plots in plots, custom plot functions etc).

I would like to change the default font to Times New Roman or Arial. Is it possible to do it globally or on a per session basis? I can't go through my script and change every `plot()` or `text()` etc. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the settings at the beginning of your session using `par(family="the-font-you-want")`. If not overwritten afterwards this will affect all the plots in your session.

```
par(family="HersheyGothicEnglish")
plot(1:10, main="Stylish Font Family")
```

The number fonts that come along in R are quite limited though (see `family` parameter in `?par`). You can extend the number of fonts you can apply (to use e.g. Arial) using the `extrafont` package.
[Here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html) you will find a good explanation of how to do that.